# Exponent of a matrix and commutative property

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups

A question given at lie group theory course:

$P$ and $Q$ are $n \times n$ matrices, and some $k \in \mathbb{R}$. Assume that $$\displaystyle\forall_{x,y \in \mathbb{R}} e^{xP}e^{yQ} = e^{xyk}e^{yQ}e^{xP}$$ Show that $k=0$ and $PQ = QP$.

It seems that the trick is to differentiate both sides and substitute $x=0$ or/and $y = 0$. When differentiating first by $x$ and then by $y$ or vice versa and substituting $x,y=0$, I, indeed, get $PQ = k + QP$. Am I right? And what about $k=0$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. Now take the trace in the equality $PQ = k + QP$ to deduce that $k = 0$.

Comment: Thanks! Totally forgot about that.

Comment: You are welcome. A last remark: If you hand in your homework you should be clear about what exactly $k + QP$ means.